# CSS selector combination syntax

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using jqGrid for a project and inspecting the styles it uses I find selectors such as this:

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-row-ltr td { 
... 
}
```

`.ui-jqgrid` is of course a class.

`td.ui-row-ltr` is a selector for class `ui-row-ltr` as applied to a table row element.

So to my questions:

1. What does it mean that they are separated by a space? I know comma separation `.class1, .class2` means "Apply to class1 and class2", but what does space separation mean?
2. What does the `td` at the end mean? `td.class` I understand but `class td`?

Comment: ... This is fundamentally basic CSS... It means "a `<td>` that is a descendant of a `<tr class="ui-row-ltr">` that is a descendant of `<___ class="ui-jqgrid">`"

Comment: Aha, so it is a series of child selectors then?

Comment: @FredrikLindqvist not a series of *child selectors* but a series of *descendant selectors*.

Comment: @FredrikLindqvist if for example you replace the spaces with "greater than" symbols (`>`) you will get a series of *direct child selectors*. Such as `.ui-jqgrid > tr.ui-row-ltr > td` which is stricter than `.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-row-ltr td`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Space separation between CSS selectors means that the latter selector is a descendant of the former.

   (Example: `div .main` will select any `.main` classes that are children (of any level) of a `div` element.)
2. The last item (the `td`, here) listed is the item that will be styled.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I am marking this one as the answer because it is the one easiest to understand, and "descendant selector" is very google able :)

Comment: @FredrikLindqvist you seem to have a good grip on nuanced wording otherwise this would considered be the least explicit (although very correct) answer.

Comment: Thanks, I think(?) Out of all the great answers, this is the first one that accurately describes the parent/descendant relationship, contains the key word "descendant", and that a CSS-noob like me could understand easily :)

Answer (score 6):

This is basic CSS indeed. Here are some examples for you:

- `div.bob` selects `<div class="bob">`
- `div .bob` selects any `class="bob"` elements nested inside any div:

  - Ex1: `<div><a class="bob"></div>`
  - Ex2: `<div><span><a class="bob"></span></div>`
- Bonus: `div > .bob` selects direct descendants only (Ex1, but not Ex2 above)

Comment: thanks to @web-tiki for fixing up obvious errors. I've been using [Zen Coding/Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/) lately, perhaps a bit too much if I'm writing such obviously wrong html!

Answer (score 1):

It means that the styles contained there will be applied to all `td`s contained in `tr` with class `ui-row-ltr` that are nested inside your element with `ui-jqgrid` class.

Answer (score 1):

It is like this.

```
<div class="ui-jqgrid">
    <table>
        <tr class="ui-row-ltr">
            <td>some data</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

or may be

```
<table class="ui-jqgrid">
    <tr class="ui-row-ltr">
        <td>some data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector will basically target every `.ui-jqgrid` which has `tr.ui-row-ltr` and if this passes it will apply your css properties to each `td` inside

Answer (score 1):

Space is known as descendent combinator [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators), meaning select all elements inside that element.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine we have a table id="main" , which contains many tr's which have td's inside.
Now, the selector "#main td" means select all the elements with the tag td that are children or children of children of the element that has the id=main, not necesarily children, but any level below

so if i have 
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-row-ltr td

it means, select all the elements with tag td, that have someone above their level a parent element tr with the class ui-row-ltr, that he has above an element with the class ui-jqgrid

All this is basic css stuff, search for some tutorials to learn more
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Comment: Good link, and noob-friendly answer!

Comment: I've been told that a lot, it's a gift I have!